# Methods to remotely change virtual IP of server

Tags: windows, failover

I'm intending to use virtual IP for my failover implementation.

Setup:

- **Server A (192.168.0.1) ** - takes virtual IP of 192.168.0.10 by default
- **Server B (192.168.0.2) ** - takes virtual ip of 192.168.0.10 when server A is down

I'm using Windows machines and my current method is to run a script on another machine to check if server a has failed, and when it fail, the script will telnet into server B to add the virtual IP.

I'm wondering if there is  an alternative solution to using telnet to change to virtual IP. I want to ensure that the failover is automatic the option of getting a network administrator to add the virtual IP is out of question.

Answer (score 0):

In orde to use a virtual IP you need to build a cluster.  You didn't specify an OS version so you'll have to look up how to create one.  Clustering has been supported since NT 4.0

Comment: I'm using a Win 7 Home Premium and Win 7 Professional in the cluster. Will there be any compatibility issues or since they are not "server" OSes.

Comment: @csl, are you *serious* ?!?

Comment: You need to use a server OS.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Windows machines and my current method is to run a script on
>   another machine to check if server a has failed, and when it fail, the
>   script will telnet into server B to add the virtual IP.

This is flawed in so many ways... please have a look at [Failover Clustering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725923%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [Network Load Balancing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742455.aspx).

Comment: can you tell me more about the flaws?

Comment: You're trying to build your own homemade and totally unsupported clustering solution while the system provides you at least two ways to do it...